# How to create an object diagram with Netbeans 6.7.1 and UML Editor?

Tags: netbeans, uml, netbeans6.7, object-diagram

I haven't found an apropriate diagram type to make an object diagram. I'd like to visualize my object graphs in the application, rather than class inheritances. Currently I do that with "class diagram" but of course that's not really fine because it looks like they all inherit from eachother. Are there more diagram types for installing?

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. They currently support only a few:

> UML Diagrams
>   The NetBeans UML plugins presently supports the following UML diagrams: Activity diagram, Class diagram, Sequence diagram, State diagram, and Use Case diagram. [http://www.netbeans.org/features/uml/]

As of Netbeans 6.5 the UML plugin has ceased feature development.

The good news is that they are partnering with Visual Paradigm to provide complete UML 2.0 based functionality

Read about this in the [roadmap](http://wiki.netbeans.org/UMLRoadmap)